# Google OAuth2 API works for all scopes except the one I need, gmail.send

Tags: php, email, oauth-2.0, smtp, gmail

I've been trying to get oauth2 to work with the gmail.send scope for ages now and I'm at a complete loss of what to try next.

I've successfully authenticated my user to work with the gmail.send scope and I even tried grabbing an access token from the google oauth playground. I started with PHPMailer and Lusitantian OAuth library, and this all seems to work with google calendar requests and "https://mail.google.com/", but as soon as I try to narrow the scope to gmail.send I consistently get the following error:

> 2020-05-17 23:49:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 {base64_encoded string that comes out more or less to: user=elize.venbooks@gmail.com\x01auth=Bearer {valid access token}\x01\x01 }
>   2020-05-17 23:49:04 SMTP INBOUND: "334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ=="
>   2020-05-17 23:49:04 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
>   2020-05-17 23:49:04 SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
>   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
>   2020-05-17 23:49:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
>   2020-05-17 23:49:05 SMTP INBOUND: "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at"
>   2020-05-17 23:49:05 SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s15sm4078014iln.49 - gsmtp"
>   2020-05-17 23:49:05 Connection: closed

I know my account credentials are correct- the initial authorization to get the tokens is flawless and the same logic works to grab a usable google calendar token, as well as works every time with the full "https://mail.google.com/" scope.

The smtp connection data I'm using is as follows:

```
$this->mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$this->mailer->Port = 587;
$this->mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$this->mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$this->mailer->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
$oauthTokenScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send";
```

Things I've tried includes (but is not limited to- I've literally put in 100+ hours tweaking things and I'm sure I'll miss a few attempts here):
-Enabling "Allow Unsafe Apps" in google security settings
-Trying the League OAuth2 library instead of Lusitanian
-Replacing it all with the provided Google API library functionality
-Copying an access code directly from google playground and forcing the code to use that
-Refreshing my refresh token by revoking app access and re-authorizing

For a while at some point I got the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose" scope to work- but google requires you use the minimum scope necessary and even with that code gmail.send did not work.

It's got to the point where I've tried every combination of things I can think of and I stopped clocking the hours to the client ages ago simply because I felt bad I couldn't fix this issue. So far as I can tell the issue is with google and the gmail.send scope itself, but after trying to explain this to google it's obvious they don't agree or simply don't care.

If I can provide any other information I'm happy to, but I've run out of ideas to try and so I'm desperately hoping anyone here has any insight as to why this may be happening.

Thanks for your time!
Hoping I can get this resolved,
-Elize

Comment: I feel your pain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Google's `apiclient` library? Found at https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client.

There are some very helpful examples in that repo, and it also has its own tag here on stack overflow (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-php-client).

I would also double and triple check that everything is configured correctly in the google developers console (https://console.developers.google.com/) - credentials, oauth clients, authorized redirect uris, etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The send scope is only documented to work on the Gmail API (HTTP REST interface). If you want to use SMTP yes, it only accepts the full mail scope.

here is a Google API php client library you can use to handle a lot of this logic. To do this without using client library refer to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) if you haven't seen it.

If sending < 5MB can send to POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send

You need to set the following two HTTP headers on your request:

- `Authenication` (oauth2 token)
- `Content-Type`: "application/json"

What you should POST is a "message" having a raw field that is base64url encoded, something like (pardon the python pseudo-code):

```
message = {}message['raw'] = base64.url_encode("To: you\r\nFrom: me\r\nSubject: test\r\n\r\nbody goes here")httplib.POST(url, json.dumps(message), required_headers)
```